# PsExec to Remotely run a GUI Application

Tags: c#, user-interface, psexec

I am trying to launch a GUI application remotely using PsExec.

```
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"<path to dir>");
            info.FileName = @"C:\<dirpath>\PsExec.exe";
            info.Arguments = @"\\" + "<COmputerName>" + " " + @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\<exepath>\<exename>.exe""";
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.RedirectStandardError = true;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

            Process o = Process.Start(info);
```

The issue here is that the process does launch remotely, but I cannot see the GUI. I can only see it in task manager.
Is there a way to see the *GUI* on the remote computer?

EDIT 1:
****Permissions****

1. Console.WriteLine (System.Environment.UserName.ToString());
2. Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.ToString());
3. Console.WriteLine ("current winddentity " + System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString());

If I execute above lines of code before starting process, it gives:

administrator

*blank*

*DomainName*\administrator

and I am logged it with the administrator account on the remote computer as well.

****InteractiveMode****
When I try to use the switch -i from the cmd prompt it gives:
Process exited with error code -1073741502.
While trying to execute using C#, it doesnt do anything at all. No exception at least!

END OF EDIT 1.

Comment: Most likely a user vs desktop issue. Who is logged on the remote machine? Which account (user) is launching the remote app?

Comment: @adelphus please see Edit 1, I added permission details.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming correct permissions you want `-i` for interactive mode.

> **-i**    Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the specified session on the remote system. If no session is specified the
>   process runs in the console session.

```
info.Arguments = @"\\" + "<COmputerName>" + " -i " + @"""C:\Program F...
```

Comment: Please see EDIT 1 I have added result of executing with interactive mode, thanks.

Comment: There are -x and -s switches that are related to the host session, you could research those